# Does adjusting the body of a irrigation sprinkler to orient one side of the sweep cause a leak at the sprinkler unit?

Tags: sprinkler-system, irrigation, seal

Some irrigation sprinklers say to orient the sprinkler body in such a way as to set one side of the sweep, rotating the sprinkler body if that edge of spray is out of line ([Example Video](https://youtu.be/pvoBZreH8hk?t=290)). This fundamentally would unscrew the sprinkler from the lead line if rotating CCW. How does this not cause the sprinkler to leak??

Comment: you are not supposed to keep turning until it leaks ... unsrew the top and pull out  the popup part ... you will quicky realize how it is constructed and how to set it

Answer (score 1):

If the sprinkler head was installed with teflon tape (about three turns) then you can choose the orientation without starting a leak.